# using one onclick javascript function to show same div in multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am using js to show/hide div when user clicks on  tag ..
but the problem is i want to use this function in multiple a tags and it's not working 
is that possible in javascript and i wont use jquery .

javascript :

```
function showdiv(id) {
   var f = document.getElementById('sss_div');
   if(f.style.display == 'none')
      f.style.display = 'block';
   else
      f.style.display = 'none';       
}
```

html:

```
<a class="class" href="javascript:void(0);" id="id" onClick="showdiv('sss_div')">click here </a>



here is the div :

<div id="sss_div" style="display:none;"><textarea></textarea></div>

any suggestions ??
```

Comment: You are not using the `id` paremeter on `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @Beterraba how do you know, we dont see the div

Comment: It's working fine **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/9Ypmw/)**

Comment: "it's not working" is an insufficient error description

Comment: @phylax Just look at the function, and you will see that he does not use the function paremeter...

Answer (score 2):

```
var f = document.getElementById('sss_div');
```

Will only select the 'sss_div' element, you should use the param id.

```
var f = document.getElementById(id);
```

Comment: @user3452363: It works if you gave the target divs individual `id` values, and used those when calling `showdiv`. For anything else, you'll have to be more thorough/specific in your question.

Comment: I tried it and it works fine, something else must be wrong... can you provide us a Fiddle?

Comment: yes it's working very fine just if i clicked on one <a> 
but if i want to use it in many links <a> it's show me only what i indicate the function to execute by the (id) and that's logical !!